# gawk - Dynamic creation of text file using input file fields

Tags: text-processing, gawk

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
UICEX_0001  UICEX_0001_T1.bam   UICEX_0001_C2.bam   chr1:16946335   chr19:9064309   chr8:10480278                                                                               
UICEX_0003  UICEX_0003_T1.bam   UICEX_0003_C2.bam   chr1:16974893
```

I am trying to use this information to create something like the following, combining strings and dynamically inputting information from the text file.  I want to:

- loop through each line
- assign the first three columns to variables
- print some text with those variables
- then loop through the 4th-end column
- print something specific.

Here's an example of my output file:

**Output File**

```
load UICEX_0001_T1.bam
load UICEX_0001_C2.bam
goto chr1:16946335
collapse
snapshot UICEX_0001_chr1:16946335.png
goto chr19:9064309
collapse
snapshot UICEX_0001_chr19:9064309.png
goto chr8:10480278
collapse
snapshot UICEX_0001_chr8:10480278.png

load UICEX_0003_T1.bam
load UICEX_0003_C2.bam
collapse
snapshot UICEX_0003_chr1:16974893.png
```

**What I've tried**

I thought I could do this by nesting gawk commands.  Here's one I've tried:

```
SAMPLEFILE = "2016-10-13_mutation_table.txt"
gawk -F";" 'BEGIN{
gawk -F";" -v SAMPLE=$(cat $SAMPLEFILE | cut -d"\t" -f1) -v BAMT=$(cat $SAMPLEFILE | cut -d"\t" -f2) -v BAMN=$(cat $SAMPLEFILE | cut -d"\t" -f3);}{print "new \nload " $BAMN;}
{print "new \nload " $BAMT;}
{awk "{for(i=4; i<=NF-1; i++){ print "goto " $i ; print "collapse\nsnapshot " $SAMPLE"_"$i".png";} }" 2016-10-13_mutation_table.txt;

}END{print "exit \n"}'
```

But running this gets errors such as this:

```
gawk: cmd. line:2: gawk -F";" -v SAMPLE=$(cat $SAMPLEFILE | cut -d"\t" -f1) ...
gawk: cmd. line:2:                     ^ syntax error
```

Comment: ... hard to say where to start. This code is a real mess. You are embedding two separate awk one-liners inside an awk script. Try formatting your own code with more whitespace and indentation, and you might see some of the problems.

Comment: Also, in shell, there must not be any spaces around the `=` in a variable assignment

Answer (score 1):

```
try this

$ awk '{printf("load %s\nload %s\n",$2,$3);for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){printf("goto %s\ncollapse\nsnapshot %s_%s.png\n",$i,$1,$i)}}' test.t
    load UICEX_0001_T1.bam
    load UICEX_0001_C2.bam
    goto chr1:16946335
    collapse
    snapshot UICEX_0001_chr1:16946335.png
    goto chr19:9064309
    collapse
    snapshot UICEX_0001_chr19:9064309.png
    goto chr8:10480278
    collapse
    snapshot UICEX_0001_chr8:10480278.png
    load UICEX_0003_T1.bam
    load UICEX_0003_C2.bam
    goto chr1:16974893
    collapse
    snapshot UICEX_0003_chr1:16974893.png
```

Answer (score 1):

What you *seem* to be asking for can be done as

```
awk '
  NR > 1 {print ""}
  {
    printf("load %s\nload %s\n", $2, $3);
    for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) {
      if (NF > 4) printf("goto %s\n", $i);
      printf("collapse\nsnapshot %s_%s.png\n", $1, $i);
    }
  }
' samplefile
```